# How to extract keyless values from json array using jansson

Tags: c, jansson

I want to extract strings from a JSON that doesn't have the key descriptor in front of the values but where the values are simply separated by a '|'.

This is an example of the kind of input I have:

```
{"data":["this|is|an|","example|thank|","you|very|much|"]}
```

Note that on the documentation, the [Jansson](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/2.10/apiref.html#array) fuctions that i find helpful always have a key as argument (but my array only have strings without a key). If someone could help i will be very thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For elements of an array you don't need any keys as you can access them via index.

First you get the array itself as a json object:

```
int result;
json_t *data = NULL;
result = json_unpack(json_p, "{s:o}", "data", &data);
```

Then you can get the elements:

```
int num_data = 0;
if (data != NULL && json_is_array(data))
  num_data = json_array_size(data);

for (int i=0; i<num_data; i++)
{
   json_t *one_elem = json_array_get(data, i);
   // Do whatever has to be done...
}
```

Comment: thanks, this did the trick: json_string_value(json_array_get(arrayData, i)));
I will accept your awser! :D btw, do you know some function in c that initializes multiple strings with the values between the pipes(|) ?

Comment: Glad to help. Nope, you will have to do it manually in a loop. `strtok` will help to split the string, but allocation and assigning the tokens is your job. ;)

Comment: Yeah, find it. I might use strsep, because strok looks obsolete in man pages. Thankz ;)

Comment: Maybe, but `strtok` is a standard C function, while `strsep` is not.